# MyBase can not to be used in a Extension Method?

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I created a module to add some [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to a Class.
This Class inherits from another parent Class.
In the code of my Extension Methods, I would like to refer to the base Class using MyBase.

This doesn't seems to be allowed (Error message : "*'MyBase' is not valid within a Module.*")

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Get_OutOfSpace(val as ClassA) As Boolean
    Return MyBase.IsOutOfSpace()
End Function
```

How can I invoke a method of my base class within an Extension Method?

Comment: What scope is the method that you want to access?

Comment: The method is protected. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why they force you to write extension methods in a module, so you can't make the mistake of using MyBase.  But there's at least one other thing wrong with your code, *you didn't extend anything*.  The first argument of an extension method must be a reference to the object, of the type you want to extend:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Get_OutOfSpace(ByVal obj As Foo) As Boolean
    ''...
End Function
```

So a likely implementation is `Return obj.IsOutOfSpace`.  Which in turn makes it very likely that you don't actually have any use at all for this extension method since the class you want to extend already has an IsOutOfSpace property.

Only use extension methods to add methods to classes.  And only do so if you can't change the class.

Comment: I will correct my code. you are right. And the comment of @chriseyre is correct too. I can not call a protected method.